# NoSuchElementException from reading from a file

Tags: java, file, file-io

So i'm trying to read the first 4 variables from each line in a text file.

But it catches the `NoSuchElementException`.

```
public static void readRecords()
    {
        System.out.printf("%s%s%s%s" , "Team Id", "TeamNAme","CoachFirst", "CoachLast");
        try
        {
            while (input.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.printf("%s%s%s%s",input.nextInt(),input.next(),input.next(),input.next());

            }

        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException statException)
        {
            System.err.println("File improperly formed.");
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException stateException)
        {
            System.err.println("ERROR READING FROM FILE");
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

This is the text File elements:

```
TeamNumber,Team Name,Coach First,Coach Last,Mentor First,Mentor Last,Team Fin Sponsor,Schools or Sponsoring Organization,TmMem1First,TmMem1Last,TmMem2First,TmMem2Last,TmMem3First,TmMem3Last,TmMem4First,TmMem4Last,TmMem5First,TmMem5Last,TmMem6First,TmMem6Last,TmMem7First,TmMem7Last,TmMem8First,TmMem8Last
6842,Reagan Ray-Guns,Judy,Mallon,Aziz,Valdez,Texas Workforce Commission,REAGAN H S,Steven,Cepeda,Alan,Yue,Tim,Callaway,Damon,Bertucci,Samuel,de Olvieira,Samuel,Day,,,,
6888,Islanders,Judy,Maldonado,Brady,Trevino,Three Rivers Robotics,THREE RIVERS MIDDLE,Shireen,Cowdrey,Dee,Roundtree,Steven,Callaway,Francisco,Bermea,,,,,,,,
7004,GREENHILL Tops,Kanat,LaBass,Harvey,Pflueger,GREENHILL Boosters,GREENHILL SCHOOL,Harvey,Pflueger,Sandra,Day,Denny,Rodriguez,shirley,Couvillon,Carly,Szarka,,,,,,
```

Comment: can you send me the sample output your expecting?

Comment: Move the try catch inside the while loop and you should be good. Also, you can skip the first line of input since it represents headers.

Comment: How is `input` initialized?  Why are you using `nextInt()` for all four fields?

Comment: @Dilip i'm expecting to read first 4 elements of each line, this code let me read the entire line after giving me the NoSuchElementException error

Comment: @bot actually i wanted to print that. it works but it reads each line not first 4 elements of each line

Comment: @pathdinerelite its initialized a couple lines before. its a long code but i wrote the relevant block of it

Comment: @DkgMarine Why don't you just use the debugging capabilities of your IDE?

Comment: @LigamentThrasher still a beginner and do not know much about it

Comment: @DkgMarine I assume your Scanner is using `,` as a delimiter?

Comment: @DkgMarine Don't overlook debugging though. It's an absolutely crucial skill to have as a programmer. Try to learn the capabilities of your IDE. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are reading in 4 variables, but each line in your sample text file has more than 4 entries (assuming you are using `,` as your Scanner delimiter).  This means that you need to call `Scanner#nextLine()` to skip the rest of the input on the line.

```
public static void readRecords()
{
    System.out.printf("%s%s%s%s" , "Team Id", "TeamNAme","CoachFirst", "CoachLast");
    try
    {
        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.printf("%s%s%s%s",input.nextInt(),input.next(),input.next(),input.next());
            input.nextLine();  // skip remainder of line
        }

    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException statException)
    {
        System.err.println("File improperly formed.");
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException stateException)
    {
        System.err.println("ERROR READING FROM FILE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got a single check for next element (`hasNext()`) method, but then, invoke `nextInt()` four times.

You should check if there are more ints, each time you invoke `nextInt()`. Also use `hasNextInt()`, instead.

Comment: This isn't needed if he can be sure that each record has exactly four fields, but it is certainly safer.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your input doesn't actually start with an `int`, so calling `nextInt()` on it will fail. Presumably you want to skip over that line first before reading the actual data that follows.